# How would you render soft returns in a Richedit control?

Tags: windows, delphi, richedit

In an application that displays a richedit control I would like to be able to visually distinguish soft returns (produced with SHIFT ENTER) from hard returns (produced with ENTER).

I already use the JVCL richedit and don't want to switch at that point.

How would you proceed to do that?

Microsoft Word may be an inspiration source, they display a ↵ sign for soft returns and a ¶ sign for hard returns at the end of each line.

I am just looking for hints, good ideas how you would tackle this project. I am not asking anybody to do my work, of course. :-)

Comment: I'd use a control like synedit or scintilla that already has such functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not a direct answer to your question, there is a possible solution to the problem you mentioned of needing to use both Richedit and Syntax highlighting in one control and that is the use of SynEdit.

SynEdit include some non-visual components that allow exporting syntax formatted text, one of those components is `TSynExporterRTF`.

Suppose you have a section of code which is in plain text inside your richedit and you want to syntax highlight that portion, you could select and copy that text to a `TSynEdit` and then export it to a `TSynExporterRTF` which will now contain syntax formatted text (assuming a highlighter has been defined correctly). Then you can simply write the data to a `TMemoryStream` and replace the selected richedit text with the now syntax formatted code.

To do this you can try something like this:

```
procedure SyntaxFormatRichEditText(RichEdit: TRichEdit; SynHighlighter: TSynCustomHighlighter);
var
  SynEdit: TSynEdit;
  SynExporterRTF: TSynExporterRTF;
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  SynEdit := TSynEdit.Create(nil);
  try
    SynEdit.Highlighter := SynHighlighter;
    SynEdit.Lines.Text := RichEdit.SelText;

    SynExporterRTF := TSynExporterRTF.Create(nil);
    try
      SynExporterRTF.Highlighter := SynHighlighter;

      MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        SynExporterRTF.ExportAll(SynEdit.Lines);
        SynExporterRTF.SaveToStream(MS);
        MS.Seek(0, soBeginning);
        RichEdit.SetSelTextBuf(MS.Memory);
        RichEdit.SetFocus;
      finally
        MS.Free;
      end;
    finally
      SynExporterRTF.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SynEdit.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SyntaxFormatRichEditText(RichEdit1, SynPasSyn1);
end;
```

If anything though, as others have suggested the requirements you need are likely out of scope as to what the Richedit controls can offer.

Comment: If the program can import from or export to clipboard then it can do the same from/to memory

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have edited my answer with code and now works in memory not clipboard, although I am unsure how off-topic/relevant this is to original posters needs? I do not have enough points to write a simple comment which is what I would have done.

Comment: Your answer is quite relevant I think. I upvoted it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you very much, and +1 for your comment on not using the clipboard and using memory instead which is obviously the more natural way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

> I already use the JVCL richedit and don't want to switch at that point.

The JVCL rich edit control wraps the Windows rich edit control. The Windows rich edit control won't show whitespace the way you desire. It has no functionality to do so. If you want the control to display such symbols you'd need to paint them yourself and I doubt that can be done in a very effective and slick way.

It sounds like you are displaying code because you mention syntax highlighting. In which case a rich edit control is the wrong choice. You should use a control designed for displaying and/or editing code.

Comment: @EmmanuelIchbiah: You can always write your own control from scratch! If done well, that is always a method that can give you precisely what you want. Like David, I doubt that RichEdit is the right option for you.